# Samsung Touchwizz: disable alarm control with physical button

Tags: alarm, volume-control, samsung-touchwiz

I'm the <del>happy</del> owner of a Samsung Galaxy S4 mini Duos, and that <del>fantastic</del> phone comes with touchwizz, probably one of the most horrible android version I ever see.
But I'm not here to insult Samsung, when you set an alarm and it rings if you have the misfortune to type one of those <del>insulting word</del> volume rocker button it just turn off your alarm without snoozing it.

My question is then, own can I disable forever that behaviour who is to me like one the most annoying ever on this phone and probably on any touchwizz rom ( the first being the profanity checking on Samsung keyboard that can't be avoided )
If it can in fact disable any physical button control on the alarm that would be fantastic.

And please do not try to tell me to install another alarm app that's not what I want.
**Edit 1**: If it means modifying system file with root access I'm interested though.

Comment: "please do not try to tell me to install another alarm app that's not what I want"... Emmm. I do feel your pain, but it's the only way I can find. If you don't want to install an app, you probably don't want to install a new ROM then? I've gotten rid of touchwiz on my S4 and I would never look back! If you are rooted WANAM XPOSED may help also as it has modules to tweek nearly everything in touchwiz / android.

Comment: The S4 mini DUOS does not have yet any rom and I have try any update to get ride of a bug in touchwizz and Now I locked with knox flag, but the first day a real alternative to that ^µù^µùµ^µ^ touchwizz exist I leave it, or I'm seriously considering to sell my phone also.

Comment: Knox is an absolute pain alright, it's up to you if you want to 0x1 it. But for the sake of this one issue, I'd say just bite the bullet and get another app for it, for now. I know it's not what you want, but if it solves the issue it might be worth it. Have a read about Wanam Xposed and see if there are any modules/tweaks for the Touchwiz alarm. It's a great thing to have, if you have a rooted phone and allows a HUGE amount of customisation without the need for another ROM. I can't find an alarm tweak here but I'm runnign Stock 4.4.2 (Kitkat) on my S4 at the moment so no Touchwiz!

Comment: Well as stated before I'd love to uninstall that **** stock ROM but there's none and even rooting is not possible without voiding that £$^%ù flag. I don't want to use another app because I add so much problem in the past with them like battery drain, not ringing alarm well nothing's more reliable than stock app for a "based on hour" app.

Comment: Yeah I hear you. I rooted despite knox as it's my device and I'm not letting a flag determine what I do on it. But obviously that's a personal choice. Many 3rd party alarms are a bit dodgy, but you're kind of trapped then.

Comment: Ok, Google have bought Timely alarm clock and it is now free on the play store. That might be a compromise, as it is now an official Google App. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.bitspin.timely&hl=en_GB

Comment: Well, it does look like a reliable app, I'll give it a try if it's reliable enought I could aware that answer.